# React native with typescript - how to use the useRoute from @react-navigation/native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get my **incident** object from `route.params` but I don't know how to do it to make typescript recognize this prop.

Here is the function that navigate to my **Detail** page passing **incident** to params:

```
const navigateToDetail = (incident: IncidentProps): void => {
    navigation.navigate('Detail', { incident });
  };
```

And Here is part of Detail page code where I try to get this object from route.params:

```
type IncidentRouteParams = {
  incident: IncidentProps;
}

const Detail: React.FC = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();

  const incident = route.params.incident;
```

I think I need to pass this **IncidentRouteParams** type somehow to **const route = useRoute()**

Thanks in advance.

Here is the image with the error:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I did like this, and it worked, but I don't know if it is the right way:

```
  const route = useRoute<RouteProp<Record<string, IncidentRouteParams>, string>>();

  const incident = route.params.incident;
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just did this yesterday!

TLDR: 
First you need to define a type with each screen name and the params it receives:

```
type ParamList = {
  Detail: {
    incident: IncidentProps;
  };
};
```

Then you use that param and the screen name in `RouteProp`:

```
const route = useRoute<RouteProp<ParamList, 'Detail'>>();
```

Here are the docs explaining all this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript

Comment: I was getting a similar issue, but `params` did not exist. I had to add `| undefined` basically to the Detail portion of the type definition

Answer (score 15):

You can also create a type considering the ParamList you want, so you only need to import this type into your component and pass the RouteName as parameter.

```
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' };
};

export type RootRouteProps<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList> = RouteProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  RouteName
>;
```

Usage:

```
export const Feed = () => {    
    const route = useRoute<RootRouteProps<'Feed'>>();
    return <Text>{route.params.sort}</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too complicated.  There is an easier way to set initialParams in TS.

Set up:

```
type StackParamList = {
  TheSource: { endpoint: string; type: string;};
  BenefitDetail: React.FC;
  ItineraryMain: {reFetch: boolean;};
  Today: React.FC;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<StackParamList>();
```

Then when using it:

```
const TheSourceRoute = (): React.ReactElement => {
  return (<StackNavigator id="TheSource" element={
    <Stack.Screen name="TheSource" component={WebviewModal} initialParams={{ endpoint: sourceUrl, type: 'directsource' }}
      options={{
        title: 'The Source',
      }}/>
  }/>
  );
};
```